# Joomla modules styles and script not included in template head

Tags: joomla3.9

I encountered a very strange issue today with Joomla. I developed a site on my local machine and everything seem to be working fine. 
See Image of the source head element below:

[image]

All the modules were displaying as expected. However, when I moved the site to my host on the remote server, strangely the styles and scripts for the modules could not be found and my modules are scattered without styling.

[image]

What could this mean? I have searched everywhere on google and here on StackOverflow, but it seems no one had experienced such an issue. Could somebody please help me out? what should I look out for?
The template I am using (zeta) is a custom template renamed from the original Joomla Protostar template.
I am using Joomla! 3.9.13, PHP 7.3.1, and Ipage.com Servers.
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It was a caching issue! I disabled the plugin page cache, disabled the system caching in the global configuration, disabled Gzip compression in the global configuration and there you go. everything returns to normal. If you ever experience a similar issue, just try the above out. Thank you to anyone who saw the question.